# Server is not looking for node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, systemjs

I am trying to deploy my application to a web server which has an application added to the default website. I used System.js to set the baseURL and enabled the defaultJSExtensions to be true:

```js
<script>
        System.config({
            baseURL: '/foo',
            defaultJSExtensions: true        
    });

    System.import('Scripts/typescript/main.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

The problem comes when it's trying to search for my js files, such as "/foo/node_modules/angular2/core.js". It is not searching for the node_modules folder, it is simply looking for "/foo/angular2/core.js".

In my local environment, this all works perfectly fine, it automatically looks for the "node_modules" folder, but when I publish it to the server, it doesnt.

I saw some solutions to add the paths option to my system.config, but I am curious as to why I don't need to do this in my local web server but I do in my test server? Is it because I don't have the "foo" site name in my local environment?

Do I need to install nodejs on the server?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you added any base path in your main HTMl file? like  <base href="foo/" />, are you using any build tool like Gulp\Grunt to publish files?

Comment: I'm simply using Visual Studio 2015 to publish right now. I have not added any base paths other than what is shown in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

you have to introduce map in the system config

```
    System.config({
        baseURL: '/foo',
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        map: {
           "<angular import>": "<adjust URL based upon your structure>node_modules/angular2/core.js"
        }      
      });
```

Comment: I'm not completely clear on how this works. I used the baseurl '/foo' .. what do you mean by <angular import> . Can you give me an example of using this? 

This still doesnt answer to me why it works fine locally but not on the server. Why do I need to add the map on the server?

Comment: you have to provide the baseurl from where your content will be renderd all the paths will be relatie to that. hence if you add baseUrl it will mimic your server configuratio, otherwise you have to map the angular source file path using map configuration, does that answers your quetion? where you able to resolve using baseUrl?

Comment: Adding the baseURL helped with System.import piece. I'm just unclear on exactly why in my local environment I don't need these mappings but on the server I do. I'm not really familiar with deploying websites to a server in general.

Comment: when you publish from VS studio it dumps to a folder and the files are served relative to that, so you get localhost/..path and when you deploy it takes serverIdentifer/<folder>/..path, hence adding baseUrl lets server know where to look for all the content files.